# Send message with actionresult

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, azure-functions

I need to return the server error from azure functions.

Now I implement the same using `InternalServerErrorResult()`. It only sends the error code and no response/message can be sent with this function.

How to implement an exception handler where the error code and message can be sent together using `actionresult` in azure functions

## current implementation

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation("An error occured {0}" + ex);
                //json = new Response(ex.StackTrace, AppConstants.ErrorCodes.SystemException).SerializeToString();
                return (ActionResult)new InternalServerErrorResult();
            }
```

this returns with an empty response in postman with error 500

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that this is from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace:

```
var result = new ObjectResult(new { error = "your error message here" })
{
    StatusCode = 500
};
```

Based on configured formatters it will return serialized object to client.
For JSON (it's default) it will return following:

```
{ "error" : "your error message here" }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a message with the status code you can use `return StatusCode(httpCode, message)`, which is an [ObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

For example:

```
return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred");
```

You can also pass an object (example using [HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-2.2) enum):

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, json);
```

Comment: `StatusCodeResponse` has no constructor with 2 arguments.

Comment: @AramKocharyan You're right, my mistake when writing answer. I've update my answer

Comment: `StatusCode` is function that is defined in `ControllerBase`. OP is asking about Azure Functions. Btw `StatusCode` again has no overload for 2 arguments.

Comment: @AramKocharyan it definitely does in asp.net core. [You can check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-2.2), not sure about azure functions though